# Java Update Push to non-admin users

Tags: java, updates, push

I would like to Push Java Update to many different PCs that are used by non-admin users on an internal network.

Is this possible without purchasing of third-party software?

PCs are mostly on Windows 7 Enterprise and some are XP Enterprise.

Java version are different from 7.11 to 7.17.

Hardware is all Dell (OptiPlex 7010 , 755, 7xx) - Processors, Core 2 Duo to new i3, i5, so some PCs have Ivy Bridge.

BIOS version are different, I know that the newest one is DELL A09.

PCs are on the same domain.

Comment: Are they on a domain? or do you have a load of stand alone machines?